# React router - Route is not displaying content of submenu element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm beginger with React.

I am trying this https://reactrouter.com/ react router in my first APP.
**My problem is**, that when I **click** at **submenu-1 or submenu-2**, it **doesn't show** my **content**. The **/** aka **home** element at **exact path** works well.

*I will accept advices about code strucutre as well, if you see some mistakes. It is my first react app. Thank you.*

My code looks like this:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.scss';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header>
                <MainNavigation/>
            </header>
            <body>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/menu-1" component={SubNavigation}/>
                <Route path="/menu-1/submenu-1" component={Content1}/>
                <Route path="/menu-1/submenu-2" component={Content2}/>
            </Switch>
            </body>
        </div>
    );
}
```

export default App;

**mainNavigation.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

const MainNavigation = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav className="navigation">
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                <Link to="/menu-1">Menu - 1</Link>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
}
export default MainNavigation
```

**subNavigation.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

const SubNavigation = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav className="navigation">
                <Link to="/menu-1/submenu-1">Content 1</Link>
                <Link to="/menu-1/submenu-2">Content 2</Link>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
}
export default SubNavigation
```

***Content1 (2 same)***

```
import React from 'react';

const Content1= () => {
    return (
        <p>Habíbo habíbo</p>
    )
}
export default Content1
```

*P.S. I have renamed all the names of functions and links in structure, so the orientation is easier for others.*

Comment: Can you provide an example of `content1` and `content2`, please?

Comment: @Enijar For now, there is really just the <p> element with some Lorem Ipsum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your navigation `<Link>` links to `"/menu-1/content-1"` but the router `<Switch />` checks for `"/menu-1/submenu-1"`.

You should use the same name. A good rule of thumb is to always use contants instead of typing twice the same string.

It would be a lot less likely to make mistakes if you wrote it like this:

```
const Paths = {
   Root: '/',
   Menu: '/menu-1',
   Content1: '/menu-1/content-1',
   Content2: '/menu-1/content-2',
}
...

            <Switch>
                <Route exact path={Paths.Root} component={Home}/>
                <Route path={Paths.Menu} component={SubNavigation}/>
                <Route path={Paths.Content1} component={content1}/>
                <Route path={Paths.Content2} component={content2}/>
            </Switch>
...

            <Link to={Paths.Content1}>Content 1</Link>
            <Link to={Paths.Content2}>Content 2</Link>
...
```

This way you not only avoid making typing errors but you also get autocomplete
when you type `Paths.`.

If it still doesn't work, it could be because the `Switch` stops at the first path matched, and in your case the `/menu-1` path will always be matched before the `/menu-1/content-1`. You could either add `exact` to the `Paths.Menu` or put the more specific paths at the top first.

### Reorder

```
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path={Paths.Root} component={Home}/>
                <Route path={Paths.content1} component={content1}/>
                <Route path={Paths.content2} component={content2}/>
                <Route path={Paths.Menu} component={SubNavigation}/>
            </Switch>
```

## OR

### Add `exact` to `Paths.Menu`

```
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path={Paths.Root} component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path={Paths.Menu} component={SubNavigation}/>
                <Route path={Paths.content1} component={content1}/>
                <Route path={Paths.content2} component={content2}/>
            </Switch>
```

Comment: Thank you. The switch / link stuff was mistake in question. It is wrotten correctly in the code. I have edited the question. Not sure if I shall mark your answer as correct or jsut leave the edit in question.
I take note of your advice about path names, and will use it in future.

Comment: well both solutions works, but the subNavigation is not rendered in the page after this. So I get the Content1 and Content2 and correct URL, but only mainNavigation is visible after click on the submenu1 or submenu2 in nav

Comment: Well Im beginign to understand the behaviour of the router now. So, the problem is, that I have to somehow make route with content and subNav, something like this:
<Route path="/menu-1/-submenu-1/" component={SubNavigation, Content1}/> 
I believe this is a new kind of question, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @ragulin Yes, that should be a different question if you want to render multiple components for the same path. What I do usually is have multiple switches or `<Routes>` outside of the `Switch` if you want for them to always be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to rename your content1 and and content2 to Content1 and Content2 since React requires you to start every component name with a capital letter.

Also the answer from @XCS

Comment: Thank you for advice, for sure, I will make capital letters next time.

Answer (score 1):

[Switch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) selects the first `Route` that matches and does not let the other `Route`s show up.

If I understand the intention correctly, you have four routes and want the following markup:

```
/ ->
<>
  <MainNavigation />
  <Home />
</>

/menu-1 ->
<>
  <MainNavigation />
  <SubNavigation />
</>

/menu-1/submenu-1 ->
<>
  <MainNavigation />
  <SubNavigation />
  <Content1 />
</>

/menu-1/submenu-2 ->
<>
  <MainNavigation />
  <SubNavigation />
  <Content2 />
</>
```

It could be done by putting the whole `SubNavigation` and `Contents` into one component which itself uses `Switch` to exclusively match on the paths (and checks for `/menu-1/submenu-1` or `/menu-1/submenu-2`) or you can remove the `Switch` in `App.js`.

Comment: So the switch would be unique for mainNavigation and each subNavigation?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. One Switch for the main and in each SubNavigation have another one for the Content